# exterior algebra of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about exterior algebra of a sheaves of modules.
How should we look at exterior algebra of a sheaf specially highest power?I know that the highest exterior power of locally free sheaf is an invertible sheaf but for example why the highest exterior power of direct sum of n copy of $O(-1)$ is $O(-n)$?(consider these sheaves on familiar projective space)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `how should we look at $\ldots$', other than follow the definitions? For a general sheaf, the highest non-vanishing exterior power may not be an invertible sheaf as you say in the next line. If you are trying to prove the last statement, may be better to prove the general formula $\Lambda^m (E\oplus F)=\oplus_{k+l=m} \Lambda^k E\otimes\Lambda^l F$ for vector bundles $E,F$.

Comment: Actually i think this definition is complicated a little! and it is hard to work with. i want to know when we look at exterior algebra of a sheaf  the best way is definition? you are right for invertible sheaves.I editted my post.thank you.